# I just used react context, why does static context not work if I console on other components

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, the first component is the 'select language' component for example he is a Provider and the second component is for example the 'login' component as the consumer I want to take the value that has been shared from the provider how to take that value? the thing is when I console the valuation at the login component is undifined

this is my provider 
in this component there are no problems

```
import MyContext from './MyContext'
export class SelectLanguage extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading:true,
      pages:''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
}
componentDidMount(){
 const getCodeFromLocal = this.props.resGet('lang-code')||'RUWT-EN';
      Api.post('pages-content', {CODE:getCodeFromLocal})
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
          this.setState({
            loading:false,
            pages:response.data.DATA
          });
        }
      })
    }
}
render() {
    const {language,loading,code,pages} = this.state
    if(loading){
      return(
        <p>loading...</p>
      )
    }else{
      return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={pages}>
          <Form.Group controlId="selectLanguage">
            <Form.Label><b>{pages.app_setting.language}</b></Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" ref="selectLanguage" onChange={this.handleChange} value={code}>
              {language.map(data => {
                return(
                  <React.Fragment key={data.language_id}>
                    <option value={data.code}>{data.language_name}</option>
                  </React.Fragment>
                )
              })}
            </Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
        </MyContext.Provider>
      )
    }
  }
```

this is my consumer/static context

```
export class Login extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      about:[]
    };
  }
}

static contextType = MyContext;

render() {
let value = this.context
console.log(value)
return(<p>tes</p>)
}
```

why value undefined? 
even though when I console at the data provider it appears

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the context values:

**1) Use static `contextType`:**

```
let value = this.context; // checks for the context type static declaration below

MyClass.contextType = MyContext; // You already have done this
```

**Drawback** : You can use only one context type to its binding.

***As you wanted to know***: *First you bind whats the context type value you have. Application might have more context types. So you are saying that I need to bind this context(Note that it's static so it bound before the instance is created for class) and you access the value after instantiated , inside the class.*

Your code:

```
export class SelectLanguage extends Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        loading:true,
        pages:''
   };
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
```

.
.

```
}
.
.
.
// For example you can use in componentDidMount()
componentDidMount() {
 let contextValue = this.context;
}
.
.
.
MyClass.contextType = MyContext;
```

}

**2) Use Context's `Consumer`**

Wrap your component with Consumer and use as props:

```
<MyContext.Consumer>
{value => 
  <Foo bar={value}/>
}
</MyContext.Consumer>
```

**Advantage**: You can wrap multiple nested consumers and use accordingly.

**3) React hook - `useContext` (Functional components only)**

```
const Foo = () => {
   const myContextValue = useContext(MyContext);
   const user = useContext(UserContext);
   return (<h5>I used hooks for {myContextValue} for user {user}</h5>);
}
```

**Advantage**: Obviously cleaner and no wrapper hell and plug and play concept.

Comment: What is the difference
let value = this.context; // checks for the context type static declaration below

MyClass.contextType = MyContext; // You already have done this

with static contextType = Mycontext?

Comment: First you bind whats the context type value you have. Application might have more context types. So you are saying that I need to bind this context(Note that it's static so it bound before the instance is created for class) and you access the value after instantiated , inside the class. (Updated answer with code)

Answer (score 0):

I have use your code and make some changes in codesandbox. check https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-cray-in0km

Use  *React.useContext* if you want to use context value outside of render method or just wrap login render with *MyContext.Consumer*

Comment: if you use static context it must be with functional components huh?